# After I increased spark.executor.memory for pyspark, it crashed at where it used to pass. How can I get through this?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, jvm, executor

To cut it short, I used to run a piece of pyspark code in pyspark shell with default settings(driver 1g, executor 1g).

The code crashed some where because of some unknown memory leak after several loops.(I've already tried some tricks to cut the data lineage, so, the leak is still unknown)

To better inspect the source of the memory leak, I have to increase the executor memory to make it crash after more loops. And I'll take some heap dump for analyzation.

However, when I increased the executor memory to 2g, the application crashed before it start the first loop.(it used to crash at the 3rd loop). It look like this:

```
2019-09-25 10:16:29,833 WARN execution.CacheManager: Asked to cache already cached data.
Sampling success
iteration #0
2019-09-25 10:16:30,005 WARN util.Utils: Truncated the string representation of a plan since it was too large. This behavior can be adjusted by setting 'spark.debug.maxToStringFields' in SparkEnv.conf.
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pyarrow/__init__.py:157: UserWarning: pyarrow.open_stream is deprecated, please use pyarrow.ipc.open_stream
  warnings.warn("pyarrow.open_stream is deprecated, please use "
iteration 0 loss 13387.430943                                                   

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "bpr_spark2.py", line 458, in test
    bpr.build(train_data, ss, k = number_of_factors, num_iterations=80000)
  File "bpr_spark2.py", line 253, in build
    self.train(ss)
  File "bpr_spark2.py", line 353, in train
    samples = self.draw(ss).withColumn('id', functions.row_number().over(Window.orderBy('u'))).repartition(self.partitionNum)
  File "bpr_spark2.py", line 302, in draw
    while(lastSamples is None or lastSamples.count() < batchSize):
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 522, in count
    return int(self._jdf.count())
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__

  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1688.count.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task serialization failed: java.lang.StackOverflowError
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.<init>(InvocationTargetException.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor49.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1140)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
```

You may expect an extremely long call stack here. Looks like some dumping operation.

The phenomenon disappeared when I set the driver memory to 2g.
So, what is it about?

For the environment I've been using is the hadoop 3.1.2 + spark 2.4.3.
With PyArrow installed and enabled for spark.

The source code to reproduce the problem is very long, with an established database, I'll upload the py code, the database used can be found on github/moviegeek.
I'll also try to make an upload of the execution environment, it's inside the docker. But it would be costly and don't expect it would come out in days?

So, can any one tell me why the driver memory must keep in the same with executor memory?

Hers is the link to the code:
https://github.com/Heermosi/moviegeek-spark/blob/master/bpr_calculator_spark.py

I cannot find out the leak point. Configure the database and run test() to replicate the error. Any one can help?

Updated 2019/09/26:

I tried hard to print out the rdd data lineage and found out the data lineage is not really cut short!
Which means the function does not work correctly, the method posted on website promised to cut short without write files is a joke!

I'll search for other ways to make the data lineage cut.
As for now, hmmm, write to files would be a good choice.